# Start Redmine automatically

Tags: linux, phusion-passenger, redmine

I use Redmine with Passenger, RVM and Linux.  To start Redmine I use next commands:

```
su redmine
cd /www/public/redmine
rvmsudo passenger start -p 85 -d --user=pass
```

What is the best way to start it automatically when Linux starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) on our servers for these kind of things.